# Как верно задать путь в скрипте IMPORTJSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Есть скрипт Google Apps Script

```
function IMPORTJSON(url, xpath) {
  try {
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split('/');
    // Logger.log(patharray);

    for (var i = 0; i < patharray.length; i++) {
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    // Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if (typeof json === 'undefined') {
      return 'Node Not Available';
    } else if (typeof json === 'object') {
      var tempArr = [];

      for (var obj in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(obj)) tempArr.push([obj, json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if (typeof json !== 'object') {
      return json;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return 'Error getting data';
  }
}
```

Он работает прекрасно, но столкнувшись с JSON массивом, он перестает работать. Пример: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/dividends/ytd

Я подозреваю что это из за скобок []

Пример: `[{"exDate":"2018-02-09","paymentDate":"2018-02-15","recordDate":"2018-02-12","declaredDate":"2018-02-01","amount":0.63,"flag":"","type":"Dividend income","qualified":"Q","indicated":""}]`

Как заставить его работать с такими данными ?

Comment: Что значит, *он перестает работать*? Какие-то ошибки или что?

Comment: oshliaer дал верный ответ, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите позицию элемента в массиве

```
= IMPORTJSON(
  "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/dividends/ytd";
  "0"
)

|       A      |        B        |
|:------------:|:---------------:|
| exDate       | 2018-02-09      |
| paymentDate  | 2018-02-15      |
| recordDate   | 2018-02-12      |
| declaredDate | 2018-02-01      |
| amount       | 0.63            |
| flag         |                 |
| type         | Dividend income |
| qualified    | Q               |
| indicated    |                 |

= IMPORTJSON(
  "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/dividends/ytd";
  "0/paymentDate"
)

|      A     |
|:----------:|
| 2018-02-15 |
```